# CMake - Eigen3_DIR-NOTFOUND

Tags: cmake, eigen3

I am trying to build a project with CMake on Windows 10. But I keep getting this error for hours:

#### Error:

```
  CMake Error at of_dis/CMakeLists.txt:8 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I downloaded Eigen, extracted it, and added a new Environment variable called `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` with value `C:\eigen-3.3.7\cmake`. Also, I added a line to the CMake file of the project which now looks like this:

#### CMakeLists.txt:

```c
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(IMOT_OpticalFlow_Edges)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(of_dis)

include_directories(./of_dis ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( "$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/opencv/opencv3.4.1/opencv-3.4.1/build/install")
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/opencv/opencv3.4.1/opencv-3.4.1/build/install/x64/vc14/lib")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/support/Place.cpp src/support/Line.cpp src/support/Argument.cpp
    src/support/FileOperations.cpp src/frame_processing/FrameProcessor.cpp src/flow_processing/FlowProcessor.cpp
    src/edge_processing/EdgeProcessor.cpp src/detection/Detector.cpp)

add_executable(IMOT_OpticalFlow_Edges ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(IMOT_OpticalFlow_Edges ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

#### CMake GUI:

[image]

I also copied the `FindEigen3.cmake` file in my current project.
But I am still getting the same error over and over again. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try as the error message suggests? Specifically, try appending `C:\eigen-3.3.7\cmake` to your CMake variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`...

Comment: @squareskittles where can I find CMake variable to add to it? It is not in the CMake GUI

Comment: The project I am talking about is [here](https://github.com/beaupreda/IMOT_OpticalFlow_Edges).

Comment: Just add `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "C:/eigen-3.3.7/cmake")` before your call to `find_package(Eigen3 ... )` in your CMake code.

Comment: @squareskittles: Variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` helps only in finding `FindXXX.cmake` scripts, but doesn't help in finding `XXXConfig.cmake` scripts, on of which is probably located under `C:/eigen-3.3.7/cmake` directory. See [that my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60011171/3440745).

Comment: @Tsyvarev The `FindEigen3.cmake` file does appear to be present in the Eigen3 repo [here](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/cmake/FindEigen3.cmake). I thought, if available, the `FindXXX.cmake` should be the first choice in general?

Comment: @squareskittles: `FindEigen3.cmake` is present in the Eigen3 repo, but it is not **installed**: `FindXXX.cmake` script is not normally installed with the project XXX, such files are needed to be shipped with the project which **uses** XXX. Instead, `Eigen3Config.cmake` is configured and installed with Eigen3, and `C:/eigen-3.3.7` looks like installation directory for that project.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad: The line `... set "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.` in the error message means that you may set `Eigen3_DIR` variable (it is the first on the screenshot you show us) to the directory, which contains  `Eigen3Config.cmake` file.

Comment: @squareskittles adding `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "C:/eigen-3.3.7/cmake")` before `find_package(Eigen3 ... )` made the error go away. I still am facing errors in building the project in Visual Studio though.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I did as you say, but when configuring CMake the entered address goes away and the same error appears again.

Comment: So you **have** the file `C:/eigen-3.3.7/cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake`, but setting `Eigen3_DIR` variable to `C:/eigen-3.3.7/cmake` doesn't help, am I correctly understand your situation?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, that's correct. Thank you for the clarification. It is so often difficult to distinguish which approach is more suitable, given provided information. I suppose that is what comments are for. :)

Comment: If Eigen was "*downloaded and extracted*", perhaps from Github, it would seem the installation step was skipped. So, the package configuration file may still be in its un-configured form: `cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake.in`

Comment: @squareskittles: Yes, it is very seems to be so. If setting `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` helps in locating the script, then this is `FindEigen3.cmake` script which is located under given directory. So the content of the directory is like [this](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/tree/master/cmake), and it contains `Eigen3Config.cmake.in` file, not the `Eigen3Config.cmake` one.

Comment: @squareskittles [Here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) it says there is no need to install. @Tsyvarev you are right. `Eigen3Config.cmake.in` is in the directory not `Eigen3Config.cmake`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To summarize the comments for completeness:*

CMake's [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command has two modes of operation: **Module** and **Config** mode. This error essentially says **Module** mode failed, then **Config** mode failed to find the Eigen3 package:

```
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

In general, when a package XXX (such as Eigen3, for example) is installed, that package should configure the `XXXConfig.cmake` file. That way, external projects can find and use package XXX by calling `find_package()` in **Config** mode.

Because your Eigen3 package was *not installed*, the `Eigen3Config.cmake` file did not get configured. Thus, the **Module** mode search should work for you, as only the `FindEigen3.cmake` file exists in your Eigen3 directories. For **Module** mode, the path to the `FindEigen3.cmake` file must be added to the [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH), as the error suggests. Adding this line before the `find_package(Eigen3 ...)` call allows CMake **Module** mode to succeed:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "C:/eigen-3.3.7/cmake")
```

Comment: It did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today, my solution is

1. Install eigen.

```
cd path/to/eigen3.X.X (where you can find CMakeLists.txt)
mkdir build
cd build
rm ../CMakeCache.txt (only if there is one.)
cmake ..
cmake --build . --target install
```

2. set Eigen3_DIR to path/to/where/Eigen3Config.cmake/is

On windows that may be: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Eigen3\share\eigen3\cmake`

Reference for cmake projects using eigen3:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html